# Sinatra: executing code on starting or restarting my app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to execute some ruby code on the start of application. Actualy this is some SQL for creating all my tables if they are not already exists.

Nowaday I should run my sql manualy (creating new tables ordinary), but I want to  write somewhere in my helloworld.rb sql, which will execute sql once my app is started or restarded.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need place it before your get/post method.

This code is allways interpret in starting and only in starting

```
require 'sinatra'

puts 'I am starting'
puts 'I can do some SQL stuff'

get '/' do
  'hello'
end
```

This code launch only one times my print.

Comment: cool. It's so obviouse solution, but I didn't thought about it

Comment: That might work in small scale development, but in production, aren't you bound to have more than one Ruby process running, so this code would run more than once?